# Destroy Record if Dependant record is not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am tring to write a script that checks to see if the corresponding record exist. if not i want to delete the record of reference.

I am new to ruby.

```
    if Hotload.find(lead.id).exists?
      leadid = Lead.find(lead.id)
      leadid.destroy
    end
```

error message:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Hotload with id=148):
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:64:in `block in leads'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:47:in `leads'
```

UPDATE:

Here is complete Function:

```
  def leads
    load_leads = []
    truck_leads = []
    hotload_leads = []
    #I just added another route for users/:id/leads and kept users/leads because I wasn't sure if it was used anywhere else.
    @leads = Lead.where(:user_id => params[:id] || current_user.id)
    @leads.each do |lead|
      if lead.post_type == 'load'
        load_leads.push lead.type_id
      elsif lead.post_type == 'truck'
        truck_leads.push lead.type_id
      elsif lead.post_type == 'hotload'
        hotload_leads.push lead.type_id
        unless Hotload.where(:id => lead.id).exists?
          lead_id = Lead.find(lead.id)
          lead_id.destroy
        end
      end
    end  
    @saved_loads = Load.find(load_leads, :order => "#{sort_load_column + " " + sort_direction}").paginate(:page => params[:load_leads_page], :per_page => 10)
    @saved_trucks = Truck.find(truck_leads,:order => "#{sort_truck_column + " " + sort_direction}").paginate(:page => params[:truck_leads_page], :per_page => 10)
    @saved_hotloads = Hotload.find(hotload_leads,:order => "#{sort_load_column + " " + sort_direction}").paginate(:page => params[:hotload_leads_page], :per_page => 10)
  end
```

Error Now

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find all Hotloads with IDs (1590, 1479, 1478, 1468, 1476) (found 4 results, but was looking for 5)):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:62:in `leads'
```

Comment: Which object is the dependent here?

Comment: Hotload is the record that might not exist. and i do not have cascade setup on my database

Comment: can we chat on Skype or something?

Comment: well its a long shot but use find_by_id(lead.id) instead of where

Comment: my email on skype is itdepartment@loadmax.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the code to

```
if Hotload.find_by(id: lead.id).blank?
  leadid = Lead.find(lead.id)
  leadid.destroy
end
```

Comment: find throws an exception if record is not found. find_by doesn't hence the better option

Comment: and use unless instead of if, cause currently it will destroy the Lead object if Hotload exists

Comment: I thought that the .exist?   ment  "Does Not Exist"

Comment: .exists returns true if it exists and a false if it doesn't, it's like me asking you, did It work? you will return true if it did and negative it didn't. :P

Comment: NoMethodError (undefined method `find_by' for #<Class:0x0000000614ab58

Comment: Hmmm... interesting, use where then, i'll check the for which version it is available, which rails are you using.

Comment: Ruby 1.9.3 with Rails 3

Comment: well use where like unless Hotload.where(:id=> lead.id).exists?

Comment: added what i got now... with the full function... maybe something else is wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find) for `find`, you'll see that it will raise an error if one or more ids cannot be found.

Try using `where` instead.

```
if Hotload.where(:id => lead.id).exists?
  lead_id = Lead.find(lead.id)
  lead_id.destroy
end
```